# How to remove duplicated value from a column?

Tags: php, html

```
  Time      To      Status  Off-Track   On-Track
10:28 AM    gf      6233          4         4
10:32 AM    dd      3835                    7
10:40 AM    ss      3235                    4
10:43 AM    ww      6621                    5
11:06 AM    zz      3837                    7
```

Suppose this table is an multidimensional array, How to hide duplicated value from "On-Track"  column without effect other column using PHP?

I need this table

```
  Time      To      Status  Off-Track   On-Track
10:28 AM    gf      6233          4         
10:32 AM    dd      3835                    
10:40 AM    ss      3235                    
10:43 AM    ww      6621                    5
11:06 AM    zz      3837
```

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you would format this a bit: indicate what is part of a string-value within the array and what is not, what the heiarchy looks like... [edit]I think I see it now, it took me a couple of minutes.

Comment: So you want to remove that column values, but not rows with that values?

Comment: Yes only column values not rows.

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that you have asked similar questions under a different username during the last few days?

Comment: @ExternalUse : I have only one username .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you only want to remove duplicates from the 'on-track' column, you can do it using the [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method.

```
$data = array(
    'time' => array('10.28','10.32','10.40','10.43','11.06'),
    'To' => array('gf','dd','ss','ww','zz'),
    'on-track' => array(4,7,5,4,7)
);

$data['on-track'] = array_unique($data['on-track']);
```

Seeing the edit to your question, it seems you want only those values in the array that appear once. In that case, you can use the code below:

```
<?php

$data = array(
        'time' => array('10.28','10.32','10.40','10.43','11.06'),
        'To' => array('gf','dd','ss','ww','zz'),
        'on-track' => array(4,7,5,4,7)
    );
$data['on-track'] = get_values_with_count_one($data['on-track']);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data['on-track']);  //returns array(5);
echo '</pre>';

function get_values_with_count_one($input) {
    $count = array_count_values($input);
    $returnArray = array();

    foreach($count as $key=>$value) {
        if ($value === 1)
            $returnArray[] = $key;
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

Further, in place of the duplicate values, you can store a special value like -1. So your final array would be `array(-1,-1,5,-1,-1)`. When outputting, don't output the -1s. That way, you can save the location of the 5.

Comment: If you will do so, you will stun the values.. thats bad.

Comment: What do you mean by that? not sure I get you

Comment: I don't want to remove values I want to hide values which is duplicated, and that table is an example, I need to do it dynamically.

Comment: @Jennifer: I populated `$data` as an example. You can populate it dynamically from whereever you are receiving the values. As for hiding it, there is no concept of hiding values in an array. If you want to hide it from the output, then just do not display it.

Comment: Yes xbonez is right in his way , but I am not looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
$aExists = array(); // array to fill values which already exists.
foreach ($aItems as &$aOneRow){
  if (isset($aExists[$aOneRow['On-Track']])){
    $aOneRow['On-Track'] = '';
  } else {
    $aExists[$aOneRow['On-Track']] = true;
  }
}
```